# proving for cantor set: $\mathcal C=\frac13\mathcal C\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be the Cantor set. Then $$\mathcal C=\frac13\mathcal C\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C\right)$$
with $\frac13\mathcal C:=\{\frac13x:x\in\mathcal C\}$ and $\frac23+\frac12\mathcal C:=\{\frac23+\frac13x:x\in\mathcal C\}$.

In lecture we had the following proof:
\begin{align}
\mathcal C&=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal C_n \tag{1}\\
&=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac13\mathcal C_n\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C_n\right)\right)\tag{2}\\
&\supset\bigcap_{i,j=0}^\infty\left(\frac13\mathcal C_i\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C_j\right)\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\left(\frac13\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty \mathcal C_i\right)\cup\left(\frac23+\frac12\bigcap_{j=0}^\infty \mathcal C_j\right)\tag{4}\\
&=\frac13\mathcal C\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
Otherwise\begin{align}
\frac13\mathcal C\cup\left(\frac23+\frac12\mathcal C\right)&=\left(\frac13\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty \mathcal C_i\right)\cup\left(\frac23+\frac12\bigcap_{j=0}^\infty \mathcal C_j\right) \tag{6}\\
&= \bigcap_{i,j=0}^\infty \left(\frac13\mathcal C_i\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C_j\right)\right)\tag{7}\\
&\supset\bigcap_{i,j=0}^\infty \left(\frac13\mathcal C_{\max\{i,j\}}\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C_{\max\{i,j\}}\right)\right)\tag{8}\\
&=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac13\mathcal C_n\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C_n\right)\right)\tag{9}\\
&=\mathcal C\tag{10}
\end{align}

Now I have some problems reproducing the proof. I've proved myself $$\mathcal C_{n+1}=\frac13\mathcal C_n\cup\left(\frac23+\frac13\mathcal C_n\right)$$
So (1) and (2) are obvious.

But what about (3)? Why are there two different indices? And why does it hold?

Then (4),(5),(6),(7) are clear.
But why do you have to take the maximum in (8) for the subset?

The (9) follows clearly by naming the maximum $n$. (10) similar to (1)-(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3) is true because you take the intersection of a bigger family of sets, hence it's contained in the intersection of its subfamily - for $i = j$. 
8) on the other hand is true because for $i \leq j$ you have $C_j \subset C_i$ hence 8) follows because you have inclusion on each 'step' of the intersection.